# Error on dynamically allocating memory to function pointer array

Tags: c

```
int kpSize = 4;
int kpIdx = 0;

typedef int (*EventHandler) (void *);

EventHandler *keyFuncArray = (EventHandler *) malloc(sizeof(EventHandler) * kpSize);
```

I get the following error on compiling, **error C2099: initializer is not a constant** on the following line

```
EventHandler *keyFuncArray = (EventHandler *) malloc(sizeof(EventHandler) * kpSize);
```

Comment: Is your code like you posted? I mean is the keyFuncArray init outside function, as a global variable? If yes, it is wrong...

Comment: This kind of initialization isn't allowed in C. Works in C++.

Comment: **error C2099: initializer is not a constant** means that the initialization value of a global variable must be constant.

Comment: Why dynamically allocate a global array of 4 pointers?

Comment: It would be better not to hide the pointer behind a `typedef`. If you did `typedef int EventHandler (void*);` then you could increase type safety drastically and get rid of the obscure pointer-to-function-pointer: `EventHandler* keyFuncArray = malloc(sizeof(EventHandler*[kpSize]));`. I can't come up with a case where a pointer to a function pointer would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot init with `malloc` a global variable.

You must write, eg:

```
EventHandler *keyFuncArray;

int main ()
{
    keyFuncArray = malloc(sizeof(EventHandler) * kpSize)

   // STUFF:..

   return 0;
}
```

Take a look also to: [Do I cast malloc return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

You can only do declarations in the global scope. So a function call can't execute in the global scope. As `malloc()` is also a function call, it couldn't execute.

So you can declare the global pointer variable and initialize it in any of your functions (not restricted to `main` only). Since the pointer is global it is available globally after initialization to any of your functions.